# iOS SpriteKit: Motion control and Accelerometre

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-motion

Evening,

I'm developing a basic SpriteKit game where you can move your car along the x-axis using the (Tilt) Accelerometre Motion Manager.

I'm having the 2 following problem:

1. I can't find the right way to set a proper sensibility to the movement, the car or goes to shots or too fast and I can't collocate it where I really want moving the phone;
2. It works only if you keep the phone parallel to the ground.

This is the code:

```
func startMotionManager() {
        isUpdatingPlayer = true
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { [unowned self](data:CMAccelerometerData?, error:Error?) in
            if let accelerometerData = data {
                let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
                if acceleration.x > -0.05 && acceleration.x < 0.05  {
                    self.xAcceleration = 0
                } else {
                    self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75 + self.xAcceleration * 0.25) * self.playerSideVelocity
                }
            }
        }
    }

override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        let mirrorWidth: CGFloat = 15
        let min = (player.size.width / 2) + mirrorWidth
        let max = frame.width - (player.size.width / 2) - mirrorWidth
        let newPosition = player.position.x + xAcceleration * 50
        if (newPosition < min) {
            playerDidCollideWithLeftBarrier()
            player.position.x = min
        } else if (newPosition > max) {
            player.position.x = max
            playerDidCollideWithRightBarrier()
        }
        player.position.x += xAcceleration * 50
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be easier just to assign a physics body to the sprite and apply a force to that? You could also set a physics body to the screen for the bounds collision.

Comment: doing that the car movement wouldn't be reactive. There will be always a timing delay to the car to stop o change direction. I need it to be fast and super reeactive

Comment: I disagree, you can always immediately stop like this: player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0) and then move after like this: player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: speed, dy: 0))

Comment: would you write some code? This is the first time for me and I'm little lost